# Dynamic add and remove row that contains dynamic picklist value in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have one requirement where there is pick list of objects. On click of any object, I have to display all the fields related to that object in dropdown form plus one empty text field to input the value. I have add more button so that user can add another row and can enter value to another field.

Add more button adding a row but the field picklist is empty each time.

For this scenario, I made 2 components.
1. Displaying object picklist
2. Displaying fields related to object + add more button.

I have registered an event in 1 component to pass object name to other component which will used to fetch the object fields.

ObjectSearchCmpt.cmpt

```
<aura:registerEvent name="objNameToSend" type="c:SendObjName"/>
<aura:attribute name="objList" type="String[]"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary testButton">Select Object</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.objList}" var="obj">
                    <li><a id="{!obj}" onclick="{!c.getObjName}">{!obj}</a></li>
                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

ObjectSearchController.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
    helper.getObjlist(component);
},

getObjName : function(component, event, helper) {
    var selObj = event.target.id;
    $(".dropdown-menu li").click(function(){
        var selText = $(this).text();
        $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.testButton').html(selText);
    });
    var eventObj = $A.get("e.c:SendObjName");
    eventObj.setParams({"objName":selObj}).fire();
}
})
```

ObjectSearchHelper.js

```
({
getObjlist : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getOrgObjList");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid && state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.objList", response.getReturnValue());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

ObjectFieldsMappingCmpt.cmpt

```
<aura:attribute name="objFieldsList" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="numOfConditions" type="Integer" default="1"/>
<aura:attribute name="wrapperList" type="IPDataCleanUpController.WrapObjList[]"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler event="c:SendObjName" action="{!c.handleSendObjEvent}"/>

<div>
<div id="div1" class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tab_logic">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Fields</th>
                                <th>Operator</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>                    
                            <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrapperList}" var="wrap">
                                <c:FieldIterationCmpt wrapperObj="{!wrap}"/>
                            </aura:iteration>
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <a id="add_row" onclick="{!c.addARow}" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

ObjectFieldsMappingController.cmpt

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getFirstRow(component);
},

handleSendObjEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var objName1 = event.getParam("objName");
},

addARow : function(component, event, helper){
    helper.addRow(component);
}
})
```

ObjectFieldsMappingHelper.js

```
({
getFirstRow : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.initialiseRow");
    action.setCallback(this, function(data) {
        var responses = data.getReturnValue();
        var wrappers=new Array(); 
        for (var idx=0; idx<responses.length; idx++) {
            var wrapper = { 'fieldName' : responses[idx].fieldName,
                            'opVal' : responses[idx].opVal,
                           'fieldVal' : responses[idx].fieldVal,
                          }; 
            wrappers.push(wrapper);
        }
        component.set("v.wrapperList",wrappers);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

addRow : function(component) {
    var contacts = component.get("v.wrapperList");
    var len = contacts.length;
    contacts.push({
        'fieldName':'',
        'opVal':'',
        'fieldVal':''
    });
    component.set("v.wrapperList",contacts);
}
})
```

FieldIterationCmpt.cmpt

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<aura:attribute name="wrapperObj" type="IPDataCleanUpController.WrapObjList"/>
<aura:attribute name="objFieldsList" type="String[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="deleteContact" type="c:deleteContactEvt"/>
<aura:handler event="c:SendObjName" action="{!c.handleSendObjEvent}"/>


<tr>
    <td>1</td>                           

    <td>

        <ui:inputSelect multiple="false" value="{!v.wrapperObj.fieldName}" class="form-control">
            <ui:inputSelectOption text="Select Field" label="Select Field" disabled="true" class="form-control"/>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.objFieldsList}" var="fields">
                <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!fields}" label="{!fields}" class="form-control"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </ui:inputSelect>
    </td>

    <td>
        <ui:inputSelect multiple="false" value="{!v.wrapperObj.opVal}" class="form-control">
            <ui:inputSelectOption value="=" text="EQUALS" label="EQUALS" class="form-control"/>
            <ui:inputSelectOption value="!=" text="NOT EQUALS" label="NOT EQUALS" class="form-control"/>
        </ui:inputSelect>
    </td>

    <td>
        <ui:inputText placeholder="Value" value="{!v.wrapperObj.fieldVal}" class="form-control" required="true"/>
    </td>

</tr>
```

FieldIterationController.js

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {


},

handleSendObjEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
    var sendObjName = event.getParam("objName");
    component.set("v.objectName", sendObjName);
    var action = component.get("c.getObjFieldsList");
    action.setParams({
        "objName": sendObjName
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(component.isValid && state == 'SUCCESS') {

            var mapOfObj = response.getReturnValue();
            var keys = [];
            var values = [];
            for(var key in mapOfObj) {
                keys.push(key);
                values.push(mapOfObj[key]);
            }
            component.set("v.objFieldsList", keys);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Apex Controller

```
public class ApexController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<WrapObjList> wrapOList {get; set;}
@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, boolean> mapObjFields {get; set;}
public static Map<String, boolean> mapObjFields1 = new Map<String, boolean>();

@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getOrgObjList() {
    List<String> orgObjlist = new List<String>();
    Map <String,Schema.SobjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    for(String s : schemaMap.keyset()){
        system.debug('val1 is ===> ' + s);
        orgObjlist.add(s);
    }
    for(Schema.SobjectType s : schemaMap.values()){
        system.debug('val2 is ===> ' + s);
    }
    return orgObjlist;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Map<String, boolean> getObjFieldsList(String objName) {
    List<String> objFields = new List<String>();
    mapObjFields = new Map<String, boolean>();        

    SObjectType objToken = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName);
    DescribeSObjectResult objDef = objToken.getDescribe();
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields = objDef.fields.getMap(); 

    Set<String> fieldSet = fields.keySet();
    for(String s : fieldSet) {
        SObjectField fieldToken = fields.get(s);
        DescribeFieldResult selectedField = fieldToken.getDescribe();
        if(selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.STRING || 
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.REFERENCE ||
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.EMAIL ||
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.LOCATION ||
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PHONE ||
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST ||
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.MULTIPICKLIST ||
           selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.URL ||
           (selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.TEXTAREA && selectedField.getByteLength() <=765))
        {                   
                mapObjFields.put(selectedField.getName(), true);

        }else if(selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PERCENT || 
                 selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.DOUBLE ||
                 selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.DATETIME ||
                 selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.DATE ||
                 selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.CURRENCY ||
                 selectedField.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.BOOLEAN){

                mapObjFields.put(selectedField.getName(), false);

        }

    }
    return mapObjFields;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<WrapObjList> initialiseRow() {
    wrapOList = new List<WrapObjList>();
    WrapObjList a = new WrapObjList();
    wrapOList.add(a);
    return wrapOList;
}


public class WrapObjList {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldName {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String opVal {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldVal {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String fieldType {get; set;}

    public WrapObjList parse(String json) {
        return (WrapObjList) System.JSON.deserialize(json, WrapObjList.class);
    }
}

}
```

The main issue is that on the first row, it displays all the fields in dropdown but when I add another row, the dropdown becomes empty. Can we achieve this without calling server side controller again.

Thanks in advance for your help.